# Display special characters in Zend_Form_Select element

Tags: php, zend-framework, utf-8, zend-form

I'm using Zend_Form to display a simple form containing a combobox, whose data is directly extracted from the database. The values are country names in the website native language (French), containing special characters (é, è, ï, ...). My files are all in UTF-8, as well as the table and the website charset.

But all the entries containing a special character appear as empty lines.

Any idea why ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure all your script and view files are encoded on UTF-8 as well.
Make sure your connection to your DB ask for UTF-8.

On missing piece in the chain can lead to erroneous display.

Comment: Thanks ! It was the database connection which wasn't set to UTF-8